# How to install (ruby) bundler when bundler is broken

Tags: ruby, bundler

After adding

```
gem "ransack", :git => "git://github.com/ernie/ransack.git"
```

to my gemfile, I now get the error message :

```
git://github.com/ernie/ransack.git  (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError)
```

for any rails <>, bundle, or gem command.

This is with bundler version 1.0.21.

I see there is now version 1.30 on github, but the install "instructions" on the bundler site, seem to imply that it using an existing bundler to set up the new version?

http://gembundler.com/

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
Bundler.setup(:default, :ci)
require "nokogiri"
```

How can I un-install the existing (broken) bundler, and install the new version, without an older version present ?

Mike

Comment: You better use RVM. Then its so easy to just toss away broken set ups.

Comment: Can you add info about you Operating System? Since solution may depend on it!

Answer (score 3):

Bundler is just a gem like any gem, and there is no need to use Bundler to install Bundler, regardless of what the instructions tell you. It's as simple as:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
```

If you are using RVM, there may be a little more to it than this (you may have to switch to the 'global' gemset first), but not much.

Comment: 1) This is on Win Xp/ sp3, no rvm

Comment: I realize bundler is a gem, what I don't understand is where in the ruby / rails "hierarchy", bundler fits ?

The problem apparently was from RUBYOPT being set to "-rbundler/setup".

When / where is RUBYOPT set ?

I opened a new cmd prompt, and RUBYOPT was NOT set, and gem uninstall bundler ; gem install bundler DID work !

Mike